# PySide using Python3 on Ubuntu: Undefined Symbol

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, pyside

I've been switching a project from python2.7 to python3. All was good in pyhton2.7. I am using PySide and I have installed it on Ubuntu. The package exists and all the .so files are there but I get this error in python3

```
>>> import PySide
>>> from PySide import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/PySide/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8Shiboken6Object4hashEP7_object
>>>
```

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Try installing `python-qt4` and `python-qt4-devel` and see if it works.

Comment: I've already installed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using pip to install PySide but using

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

did the trick